# How can I copy all or a portion of an SMS conversation?

Tags: applications, email, sms

The built in SMS app only allows one message to be selected at a time.  I would like to copy the entire conversation or select a range and copy it so that it can be pasted into an email.  How can I do this on Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SMS Backup+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync) will backup (and can restore too) your sms messages to your gmail account (you have to enable IMAP in gmail)

The nice thing about it, it does it automatically. It can also backup your call log too email too.

Answer (score 5):

In the stock Android messaging app, you can hold your finger on a message for a few moments and then select the "Copy Message Text" option, then paste it into any app you'd like.

That would work fine for individual messages, as far as entire threads go, that I'm not sure.  I'd probably go the geeky route personally and open up the .db file that contains all the text messages with an sqlite3 binary and manually peruse the database, copying what I need out of it.

Comment: huh.. Interesting. Ok so the text messages are in a sqlitedb, eh? Where is the file located?

Comment: /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out on my own phone but my buddy isn't a programmer so most of this would be above his head.

Answer (score -1):

I'd also like through my own answer into the mix - not as an android app but as a service you could potentially use if you are an Android/gmail user. http://voice.google.com is a great tool that lets you send and receive texts through the browser as well as sending you transcripts via texts to your phone when people leave voice messages.

You are given a phone number (of your choice) which you can keep forever which in case you change phone numbers, you can always be contacted through that number (but you can block people by phone number and it says the number has been disconnected).

The idea here is that if you give that google voice number to your friend and they send you a text to that number, you will receive it in your google voice inbox as well as your phone and it keeps conversations grouped like you would expect google to do.